# Weird entries are fetched when performing sudo apt update

Tags: linux, debian, apt, upgrade, repository

Below is my `sources.list`. I have no additional files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. `(Some_Server)` is a public repository.

```bash
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb (Some_Server)/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src (Some_Server)/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb (Some_Server)/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src (Some_Server)/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb (Some_Server)/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src (Some_Server)/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

I did a routine `sudo apt update` but was alarmed by the unusual amount of entries.

```bash
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 (Some_Server)/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Get:2 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Hit:3 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm InRelease                            
Get:4 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main Sources.diff/Index [3,873 B]            
Get:5 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [3,873 B]     
Get:6 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main Translation-en.diff/Index [3,873 B]     
Get:7 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main all Contents (deb).diff/Index [3,873 B]
Get:8 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main Sources T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [539 B]
Get:9 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [453 B]
Get:10 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main Translation-en T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [199 B]
Get:8 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main Sources T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [539 B]
Get:10 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main Translation-en T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [199 B]
Get:9 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [453 B]
Get:11 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main all Contents (deb) T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [201 B]
Get:11 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates/main all Contents (deb) T-2023-08-26-0938.45-F-2023-08-26-0938.45.pdiff [201 B]
```

When I tried again later behavior returned to normal.

```bash
$ sudo apt update
sudo apt update
Hit:1 (Some_Server)/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:2 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm-updates InRelease                            
Hit:3 (Some_Server)/debian bookworm InRelease
```

What were those entries? Is the repository compromised? Should I switch to another repository?

Answer (score 2):

The repository isn’t compromised. The entries are [as follows](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format):

- `Sources.diff/Index`: [the index of available diffs for the `Sources` file](https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm-updates/main/source/Sources.diff/Index) ([these diffs allow smaller downloads](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#indices_difference_files_.28diffs.29))
- `Packages.diff/Index`: [the index of available diffs for the `Packages` file](https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.diff/Index)
- `Translation-en.diff/Index`: [the index of available diffs for the `Translation-en` file](https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.diff/Index) (English-language package metadata)

followed by the appropriate diff files to update your system (based on the files already available locally).

Your subsequent `apt update` didn’t download anything other than the `InRelease` files because nothing had changed since your last update.